# Boot issue on clean Ubuntu Server 20.04 system

Tags: ubuntu, boot, cloud-init, ubuntu-20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a hdd in my 2009 Mac pro 4,1 (flashed to 5,1). I've wiped and reinstalled 3 times at this point. All three times, The installation goes without a hitch but upon the first start-up the boot gets hung-up on
`[ OK ] Reached target Cloud-init target`

I read some forum that mentioned this issue and simply rebooted the system.

any subsequent boots get hung up on:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS *********-server tty1

*********-server login: [  32.083683] cloud-init[891]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 08 May 2020 20:58:20 +0000. Up 31.93 seconds.
[    32.767663] cloud-init[898]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 08 May 2020 20:58:21 +0000. Up 32.59 seconds.
[    32.767850] cloud-init[898]: Cloud-init v. 20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5 finished at Fri, 08 May 2020 20:58:21 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/var/lib/cloud/seed/ncloud-net] [dsmode=net]. Up 32.75 seconds.
```

Any suggestions??? The whole purpose of this project is to set up nextcloud for remote access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it really "hung up"? Because

> *********-server login:

message means you've successfully booted OS. It's just a later log messages of cloud-init which overrides it a little bit. It looks problematic but it's actually not a reason for an error itself.

Can you try pressing Enter or Ctrl+C on that screen? If it responds, just try to log in with your account.

Comment: What the heck is going on with Ubuntu? First the "curtin hook" thing and now this.  I'm tired of Ubuntu waiting on me and giving me the impression I'm waiting on it.

Comment: lol pressing enter "fixed it", as in it was finished just not showing my console, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It hasn't hung. Hit enter. or SSH to it, it works fine

Comment: I hit enter.  After a minute, it cleared the screen and showed the login prompt.  It appeared hung as I normally expected something to change every 4 seconds to indicate it is doing something.

Comment: Wow, this is all it was

Answer (score 3):

If you can gain access to the terminal you can disable early boot stage cloud-init services by creating the following file:

`sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`

Additional details on cloud-init in early boot stages of the server can be found in [this article](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it doesn't hang up, but if you want to avoid situation, then login request appears too early - you need stronger or more cores of CPU.